# Why doesn't my second table initialize in IE8?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have two Tablesorter tables in my [website demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia4/), which can be accessed by either clicking *Events* or *Venues* at the very top.

In IE8, the *Events* table loads fine, while the *Venues* table does not.

*specifically, the problem I have is that in Venues top sorting part doesn't load and neither does the Zebra widget.*

Here is the code I have for them:

**events**

```
function configureEvents() {
    $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {
        $("#eventsTable").tablesorter({  
            headers: {  
            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
            },
                widgets: ['zebra']
            }); 


            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
                jQuery("#all_events_button").addClass("topActive");
                jQuery("#today_button").addClass("timeframeActive");
                $("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 150);            
    }); 
}
```

**venues**

```
function configureVenues() {
    $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('venues.html', function() {
        $("#venuesTable").tablesorter({  
            headers: {  
            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
            },
                widgets: ['zebra']
            }); 

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();    
            $("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 150);
    });
}
```

They both have different names so I doubt there's some sort of a collision happening. Anyway, thanks for your time everyone! :)

Comment: That page never finishes loading & I see two errors: `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' complete.js, line 14 character 15` and `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'colorbox' verzia4, line 74 character 2`

Comment: Hi fudgey, that's because I'm adding some features now and ran into a couple of problems. It should be sorted within the next hour. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Okay, the site works now (except for IE8) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG... took me forever to figure it out LOL.

Basically the venues table has the class "tablesorter2"... change it to "tablesorter" and everything should work - it was sorting, just not applying the styling to LOOK like it was applied.